# Running a function/script per user on the server side

Tags: php, mysql, cron, client, server

I'm working on a basic lamp(willing to change) website , and I currently need a way to run some function on the server that runs for several hours per user, and every X hours it needs to query  the mysql database to see if the value for that user has been updated, if it hasn't it need it to insert a new record in the database...I also should mention that the 'every X hours' can change per user too, and the total runtime of the function per user can also vary.

So basically I need a function that runs continuously on the server for few hours per user. What is the best way to do this? I want the site to be able to support many users (like 10000 +).

I'm willing to try new technologies for every aspect of the site, I'm still in the design phase and I was looking for some input.

I've looked at cron but not really sure how well it would work when dealing with so many users...

edit: Here is a typical scenario of events;

- User presses button on the website and closes the browser.
- Server starts a timer from when they pressed the button, now 
  the server will check if that user has pressed a different button within a given time frame (time frame can change per user), say within 30 minutes. If they didn't  press the other button then the server needs to automatically insert a new record in the database.
  The script will need to continue running, checking every 30 mins for say the next 5 hours.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need a timer per user. You just need one: every X minutes, scan through your users in your database, and mark each one as "timer started", "no change" or "timer stopped" according to the logic you need. Cron is fine for this.

Answer (score 0):

Cron would work as well as you can code the page it will run. It's not a cron limitation.

The question is ambiguous btw. Maybe explaining your full scenario would help.

Meanwhile, my suggestion would be to set up a scrip that allows you to manually check what you need to check.

You definitely need the DB to be InnoDB optimized with proper indexes to be able to support 1000 plus users.

To alleviate the number of calls to the database, a common practice is to run scripts only on what you are interested (so in the case of users you would only select those who have logged on in say the past 3 hours)
That's achievable in 2 ways, a simple select statement, or by adding entries to a specific table on the login page, and remove them after the automated script has finished running.

All of this is pure theory without understanding exactly what you need to do though.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling **what/how** you want to do, but not **why** you want to do it. Maybe letting us know **why** could lead to a different **how** ;)

However, what you can do is still use `cron` (or anything similar). The trick is to have

- a `last_interaction` timestamp column
- a `maximum_interval` column
- a `daily_runtime` column

in your `users` database. Not optimized but you are in the design phase so you shouldn't pay too much attention to the performance aspect (except is explicitly required).

Comment: Okay I think I  understand, I've updated the question with a sample scenario. Would running a php script every minute, that checks for users that are within the timeframe and have not pressed the button.  Then for each user it inserts a record, one by one into the database? Would this take a lot of time though, if there are  many users? And what happens if the php script is running for over a minute and cron runs it again? Sorry I'm totally new to cron

Comment: You are still explaining what you want to do, and not why. Are you trying to handle sessions (e.g. if no actions from a specific user for 5 hours, you log her out of your app ?). You can also use cookies to store the last timestamp of interaction. But if you are implementing a security feature, this could be not well suited. And about the time it will take, you can test it ;) Just create 50k fake users in your database with a script and simulate severals interactions. That may even give you an even better understanding of what you are trying to do :) Good luck.